# Find the set of columns maximizing the minimum of the sum in each row

Tags: algorithm, optimization, heuristics

Given a matrix A, i’m looking for the set of p columns that maximizes the minimum on the sum of the matched cells in each row.

For example: if p=2 and A=

1   2   4

3   0   3

5   6   2

Choosing C1 and C2 would give f=min(r1,r2,r3)=min(1+2; 3+0; 5+6)=3

While choosing C1 and C3 would give f=min(1+4; 3+3; 5+2)=5 which is the best choice.

Is there any algorithm or heuristic doing so..

Thanks

Comment: What is stopping you from just using all the columns? Negative numbers? Is there any reason this problem is showing up? - it sounds a bit like an ACM challenge.

Comment: @missingno: a set of **p** columns. And I doubt ACMer will look for heuristics, but see what OP say.

Comment: @missigno as big and as small as n/2 I guess

Comment: A simple heuristic is to greedily choose columns based on the "minimum value in columns" heuristic: choose the column that has the largest minimum value, subtract those values from the rest of the array.  For example, in your case, C3 has the largest minimum, so subtract to get C1=-3,0,3 and C2=-2,-3,-4.  In the second iteration, choose C1.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is NP-hard via a trivial reduction from set cover (let A be the 0-1 matrix representing the element-set containment relation). I would try a MIP solver on the straightforward integer-program formulation, where `c(j)` is 1 if the `j`th column is taken and 0 otherwise.

```
maximize lambda
subject to
lambda <= c(1) A(i,1) + ... + c(n) A(i,n)    for all i
c(1) + ... + c(n) = p
c(j) in {0, 1}                               for all j
```